# Class template with template class friend, what's really going on here?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Let's say I'm creating a class for a binary tree, `BT`, and I have a class which describes an element of the tree, `BE`, something like

```
template<class T> class BE {
    T *data;
    BE *l, *r;
public:
...
    template<class U> friend class BT;
};

template<class T> class BT {
    BE<T> *root;
public:
...
private:
...
};
```

This appears to work; however I have questions about what's going on underneath.

I originally tried to declare the friend as

```
template<class T> friend class BT;
```

however it appears necessary to use `U` (or something other than `T`) here, why is this? Does it imply that any particular `BT` is friend to any particular `BE` class?

The IBM page on templates and friends has examples of different type of friend relationships for functions but not classes (and guessing a syntax hasn't converged on the solution yet). I would prefer to understand how to get the specifications correct for the type of friend relationship I wish to define.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
template<class T> class BE{
  template<class T> friend class BT;
};
```

Is not allowed because template parameters cannot shadow each other. Nested templates must have different template parameter names.

---

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  template<typename U>
  friend class bar;
};
```

This means that `bar` is a friend of `foo` regardless of `bar`'s template arguments. `bar<char>`, `bar<int>`, `bar<float>`, and any other `bar` would be friends of `foo<char>`.

---

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  friend class bar<T>;
};
```

This means that `bar` is a friend of `foo` when `bar`'s template argument matches `foo`'s. Only `bar<char>` would be a friend of `foo<char>`.

---

In your case, `friend class bar<T>;` should be sufficient.

Comment: this construction in my code
 
    friend class BT<T>

throws an error for the friend line

    error: 'BT' is not a template

even though it's declared later as 

    template<class T> class BT {
    ...
    }

Comment: So the secret is that I needed to forward declare BT in order to use the friend class BT<T>; line in the BE, but not for the template<class U> friend class BT;. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To be more specific: you have to forward declare `template<typename T> class BT;` _before_ the definition of BE, and then use `friend class BT<T>;` _inside_ the class BE.

Answer (score 13):

In order to befriend another same-type struct:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T_>
struct Foo
{
    // Without this next line source.value_ later would be inaccessible.
    template<typename> friend struct Foo;

    Foo(T_ value) : value_(value) {}

    template <typename AltT>
    void display(AltT &&source) const
    {
        std::cout << "My value is " << value_ << " and my friend's value is " << source.value_ << ".\n";
    }

protected:
    T_ value_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo1(5);
    Foo<std::string> foo2("banana");

    foo1.display(foo2);

    return 0;
}
```

With the output as follows:

```
My value is 5 and my friend's value is banana.
```

In `template<typename> friend struct Foo;` you shouldn't write `T` after `typename`/`class` otherwise it will cause a template param shadowing error.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to name the parameters so you get fewer points of failure if refactoring:

```
     template <typename _KeyT, typename _ValueT> class hash_map_iterator{
       template <typename, typename, int> friend class hash_map;
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make a template class a friend of a template class is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
   friend class B<T>;
private:
   int height;
public:
   A()//constructor
   A(T val) //overloaded constructor

};

template<typename T>
class B
{
private:
   ...
public:
   B()//constructor
   B(T val) //overloaded constructor
};
```

Comment: This makes a particular specialization `B<T>` a friend of specialization `A<T>`. Templates themselves can't be friends, though the closest to what this could mean is to make all specializations of one template friends of all specializations of another template (then friend declaration has to be templated - see the accepted answer).

Answer (score -5):

In my case this solution works correctly:

```
template <typename T>
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass1 {
  template<class T> friend class DerivedClass2;
private:
 int a;
};

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass1 {
  void method() { this->i;}
};
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: How is that solution supposed to work correctly when you're shadowing template parameters and otherwise not putting DerivedClass2's friend access to DerivedClass1 to use?