# Class c++ error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I've a problem, i've those class, that now works, because i've the attribute in public, but if i put it in private, or protected and inherited to the second class, it's not work, how can i do it?
I need to respect OOP rules

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryNode
{
public:
    T key;
    BinaryNode<T>* left;
    BinaryNode<T>* right;
    BinaryNode<T>* parent;
    BinaryNode(){}
    ~BinaryNode(){}
};
And this:

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    BinaryNode<T>* root;
    BinaryNode<T>* newNode(T key);

    BinaryNode<T>* minimum(BinaryNode<T>* node);
    BinaryNode<T>* maximum(BinaryNode<T>* node);
    BinaryNode<T>* successor(BinaryNode<T>* node);

    void insert(BinaryNode<T>** node, T key);
    BinaryNode<T>* search(BinaryNode<T>* node, T key);
    void distance(BinaryNode<T>* node, T key);
    void inorderTreeWalk(BinaryNode<T>* node);
public:
    BinarySearchTree();
    ~BinarySearchTree();

    void insert(T key);
    BinaryNode<T>* search(T key);
    void distance(T key);
    void inorderTreeWalk();

    BinaryNode<T>* remove(BinaryNode<T>* node);
};
```

There's the header file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8xsn3q01ysyy4f/classi.h

Can you show me how i can do?
Thanks,
Bye

Comment: What to you want to make private? What error are you getting?

Comment: The class BinaryNode, the error is with pointer, too much error in the pointers.

Comment: @Raid3nz Do you want Left, Right, and Parent to be private?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy yes, and key, What i must change in BinaryNode and BinarySearchTree Class?

Comment: @Raid3nz what error message do you get when you try to make them private?

Answer (score 0):

You can make BinarySearchTree a **friend** class of BinaryNode.

```
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree;  // forward declaration

template <typename T>
class BinaryNode {
  friend class BinarySearchTree<T>; // we only allow BinarySearchTree with the same template T access
  private:
    // make everything you want private
}
```

This way BinarySearchTree is allowed to access private fields of BinaryNode.

Note that you do not need to create empty default Constructor/Destructors.

The following lines are not necessary:

```
BinaryNode(){}
~BinaryNode(){}
```

[When should you use 'friend' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c)

[Edited: added template arguments.  See [Class template with template class friend, what's really going on here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967521/c-class-template-with-template-class-friend-whats-really-going-on-here) for other possibilities]

Comment: What's wrong here? I got error when i inherited this.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/zTsVk.png

Comment: You would need to inherit from BinaryNode<T>.  But don't do this here.  A BinarySearchTree **is not** a BinaryNode and you should only inherit if there is such a relation.  (I.e. BinarySearchTree **is** a BinaryNode).
Why don't you use my `friend` version?

Comment: I tried it, but i can use friend version, only with operator overloading

Comment: If you are trying Jerry Coffin answer (he is absolutely right btw), you misunderstood.  Put the class definition of class BinaryNode directly into BinarySearchTree:
`template... class BinarySearchTree { private: class BinaryNode {...} }`

Comment: add template <typename T> before class BinaryNode

Comment: or (better) just remove <T> from all BinaryNode<T> occurences.
It is no longer necessary to make BinaryMode a templated class.

Comment: Uhm, i didn't understand, i tried to do, but i got too much error...
There's all files, can you show me where's the problem? and how can i change it? You can test on my files?
Now it works because i've returned to Friend, but if you do as Nested class, it not works...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/atd4tif0tntz9to/header.h
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8xsn3q01ysyy4f/classi.h
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgh5pwvsd6jozpw/main.cpp
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qw7od6fysa2mr9/function.cpp

Thanks, and sorry :(

Comment: I compiled your code (I pity you for having to use windows).  Apart from some obvious errors (did you forget to delete nodes?) everything looks fine.
If you use a nested class you have to declare your functions like this: `typename BinarySearchTree<T>::BinaryNode* BinarySearchTree<T>::maximum(...) {`.
But it doesn't really change much.  Contrary to J. Coffin's statement there is no implicit Friends statement when using nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the basic idea of a `BinaryNode` is generally only meaningful in the context of the binary tree, you typically start by nesting its definition inside the BinarySearchTree class.

This has the side-effect of making the outer class a friend of the inner, so you can make all the node class' members private, and the tree can still access whatever it needs to.

Personally, I'd change at least a few other things, though they're not really related to the question you asked. For example, I'd change the `remove` to take a key item instead of a node:

```
BinaryNode* remove(T key);
```

I'd probably also change it to return something other than a `BinaryNode *`. IMO, `BinaryNode` is something of which the user should be able to remain entirely ignorant. That doesn't mean we need to (try to) deprive them of knowledge of it if they want it, but that they shouldn't normally have any real reason to know or care about it.

Comment: What's wrong here? I got error when i inherited this.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/zTsVk.png