# Can I keep the constructor of a templated class private in this situation?

Tags: c++

Given the following situation:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    Foo(/*args*/);

public:
    static Foo<T> create(/*args*/);

    template<typename U>
    Foo<U> bar(/*args*/);
};
```

I have this `create` function for users of this class to use instead of its constructor. The `bar` function needs to instantiate a `Foo` but with a different template type. This `bar` function can't use `create` because its arguments are not suited for it. This doesn't compile because, AFAIU, `Foo<T>` and `Foo<U>` are plainly different types and they can't see each other's private functions just like any two unrelated classes can't.

I've resorted to having the constructor `public` but is there a way out given the goal of enforcing instantiation through the `create` function exclusively by users of this class?

Edit: minimal reproducible example and compiler's output:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    Foo(/*args*/)
    {}

public:
    static Foo<T> create(/*args*/)
    {
        return Foo<T>();
    }

    template<typename U>
    Foo<U> bar(/*args*/)
    {
        return Foo<U>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto fi = Foo<int>::create();
    auto ff = fi.bar<float>();
    (void)ff;

    return 0;
}

main.cpp:17:16: error: calling a private constructor of class 'Foo<float>'
        return Foo<U>();
               ^
main.cpp:24:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Foo<int>::bar<float>' requested here
    auto ff = fi.bar<float>();
                 ^
main.cpp:5:5: note: declared private here
    Foo(/*args*/)
```

Comment: "This doesn't compile because," .... does it not? Please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message. One can guess what the problem is, but it isnt present in the code you posted

Comment: In case anyone comes here and incorrectly concludes that the answer is "no" by going to the first duplicate. The answer is actually found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147061/how-to-share-protected-members-between-c-template-classes) and, in the context of my question, the answer is to friend `Foo<U>` like so `template<typename U> friend class Foo;`. When you do that, the constructor can be kept private because you've now friended all possible `Foo<>` types.

Comment: the answer in the first duplicate has `template<class U> friend class A;` to make any `A<U>` a friend of `A<T>` as well. Nobody said that it isnt possible