# Templated friend class in nontemplate class, where friend also uses the class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11, c++14

### Background

I have a non templated class, called `library` and a templated class `library_file`, which is intended to have a template parameter `F` for different file types (like `std::fstream` or `QFile` and so on) to save/load a `library` on.

### Assumption

So I put a forward declaration of `library_file` before my definition of `library` and a friend declaration in the last one. Because, since `library_file` includes `library` I would otherwise be in a dependency circle.

### Problem

The friend declaration fails with

```
In file included from /Users/markus/Entwicklung/cmake_Spielwiese/library.cpp:4:
/Users/markus/Entwicklung/cmake_Spielwiese/library.h:12:12: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    friend library_file;
    ~~~~~~ ^
/Users/markus/Entwicklung/cmake_Spielwiese/library.h:12:12: error: friends can only be classes or functions
2 errors generated.
```

---

### Code

```
/*! @file library.h
 * */

#ifndef CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H
#define CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H

template <typename F>
class library_file;

class library {
    template <typename F>
    friend library_file;

};


#endif //CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H

/*! @file library_file.h
 * */

#ifndef CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_FILE_H
#define CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_FILE_H

#include "library.h"

template <typename F>
class library_file {
    F file;
    library l;
};


#endif //CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_FILE_H

/*! @file main.cpp
 * */
#include <fstream>
#include "library.h"
#include "library_file.h"

int main() {
    library_file<std::fstream> f;
    return 0;
}
/*! @file library.cpp
 * */

#include "library.h"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct declaration of a template friend class is :

```
template<class F> friend class library_file;
```

see [Class template with template class friend, what's really going on here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8967521/4884034)

Comment: Well that's embarrassing that I just forgot the class keyword. Thanks :-)

Comment: Having someone giving a fresh look to our code is sometimes all we need !

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `class` keyword in `library_file.h`, it compiles just fine after that

```
#ifndef CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H
#define CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H

template <typename F>
class library_file;

class library {
    template <typename F>
    friend class library_file;

};


#endif //CMAKE_CPP_SPIELWIESE_LIBRARY_H
```

Comment: Thanks too, but Daniel was faster :-)