# Why is T undefined? I am trying to implement a node class to use for a doubly linkedlist and it does not like the T after I use the friend operator

Tags: c++

```
class Node{
    template<class T>
    friend class DLList; 
    private:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    public:

    Node():next(nullptr),prev(nullptr){}
    Node(T val):next(nullptr),prev(nullptr),data(val){}
    Node(const Node<T>& rhs):next(nullptr),prev(nullptr),data(rhs.data){}
    ~Node();
};
```

I keep getting the T is an unknown type someone please explain to me why.

Comment: `class Node` currently isn't templated.

Comment: There is a bit more subtlety coming around the corner. Some of it is covered here: [Class template with template class friend, what's really going on here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967521/class-template-with-template-class-friend-whats-really-going-on-here) I'm looking to see if I can find a more complete answer to the problem you'll run into next.

Comment: Haven't found one yet. but `friend class DLList<T>;` as suggested by the answer linked above probably won't be enough because odds are good that by the time the compiler reaches it, it won't know that `DLList` is a template yet. You may need a `template<class T> class DLList;` to forward declare that `DLList` is a template.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
class Node{
    template<class T>
    friend class DLList;
```

the only thing that is templated is the friend. `Node` is not templated.

Solution: Make Node a template as well

```
template<class T>
class DLList; // declare DLList is a template so that it's a template when friended

template<class T>
class Node{

    friend class DLList<T>; // Node is now a friend of DLList<T> and no other DLLists 
private:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
public:

    Node():next(nullptr),prev(nullptr){} // I don't recommend having this constructor.
                                         // If T doesn't have a default constructor, 
                                         // the program will not compile and the error 
                                         // messages can be quite inscrutable.
    Node(T val):data(val), next(nullptr),prev(nullptr){}
                                         // I moved data to the front of the line because 
                                         // the members are always initialized in the 
                                         // same order as they are defined no matter the 
                                         // order they are in in the initializer list. It 
                                         // doesn't matter here, but I see it as a 
                                         // sanitation issue.
    Node(const Node<T>& rhs):data(rhs.val), next(nullptr),prev(nullptr){}
                                         // corrected this constructor to use the correct 
                                         // input value. I don't recommend having this 
                                         // constructor. 1) You Probably don't need it. 
                                         // the default constructor should be good enough
                                         // and 2) this isn't really a copy. 
    ~Node();
};

template<class T>
class DLList // now we define DLList for real.
{

};
```

But... There is a better way to do this.

We can make the `Node` a private member of the `DLList` class. Now that only `DLList` can see `Node`s, we can make all of the `Node` members `public`.

```
template<class T>
class DLList
{
private:
    class Node{
    public:
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

        Node(const T & val):data(val), next(nullptr),prev(nullptr){}
        Node(const T & val,  Node* p, Node* n):data(val), next(p), prev(n){}
                                         // Having a constructor that sets the prev and 
                                         // next pointers makes insertion logic just a 
                                         // bit easier later.
        ~Node();
    };

    // private DLList stuff goes here
public: 
    // public DLList stuff goes here

};
```

Why is this a good idea? Encapsulation. No one outside if `DLList` should know that `Node` even exists. They should certainly never be allowed to get their hands on one. Some idiot could `delete` one without properly removing it. They could accidentally mangle it. Don't give them the chance. Give them [iterators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) and give them data. Never give them a `Node`.